# Regular expression to match Macrium Reflect backup files

Tags: macrium

I want to prune old differential backup files from the files Macrium Reflect creates when it performs automatic backups.  What is a regular expression to match the type of files Macrium Reflect creates?  This is an example list for folder backups:

```
5369C2F8CBA760E6-00-00.mrbak
FE51DDEE08007D30-00-00.mrbak
FE51DDEE08007D30-01-01.mrbak
FE51DDEE08007D30-02-02.mrbak
FE51DDEE08007D30-03-03.mrbak
```

and this is an example list for disk image backups:

```
67DF99BFCF092FB4-00-00.mrimg
68279D73376C446E-00-00.mrimg
68279D73376C446E-01-01.mrimg
68279D73376C446E-02-02.mrimg
68279D73376C446E-03-03.mrimg
```

Note Macrium Reflect allows pruning full backups inside the software, but not differential backups.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches the file names:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{16}-\d+-\d+\.mr(img|bak)$
```

This part is 16 alphanumeric characters: `[0-9A-Z]{16}`

This part is a dash, folllowed by an integer, followed by a dash, followed by an integer: `-\d+-\d+`

This part is a dash, folllowed by an integer, followed by a dash, followed by an integer: `-\d+-\d+`

This part is the filename extension for the two types of files: `\.mr(img|bak)`

And the regex starts with `^` to anchor the beginning of the string and ends with `$` to anchor the end of the string.